# New array from multiplication numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have an array like this:

```
data=np.array(([2,4,8], [10, 20, 30], ...)) # TypeError fixed
```

And I want to get the result as a new array of the multiplication of each of the indices of each array:

```
np.array([[64], [6000], ...])
```

How it can be done with numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that result doesn't seem to be the "multiplication of each of the indices", but here's what you seem to want:

```
result = data.prod(axis=1)
```

Example:

```
In [2]: data = numpy.array([[2, 4, 8], [10, 20, 30]])

In [3]: data.prod(axis=1)
Out[3]: array([  64, 6000])
```

See the [docs for `numpy.prod`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html) for more information.